# Positioning of multiple elements with canvas pictures

Tags: html, css

I've got a question about positioning of multiple elements with a text right of a "picture". The situation itself is explained below. My question here is how can I best go about positioning the elements. I've tried around a bit with relative positioning, fixated and absolute, but didn't find a good functioning variant. Thus the question is if someone could give me an advice on how to best go about the positioning itself there (what should be put into relative,....)

**Situation:**
Every "part" consists of a `<div></div>` with multiple elements in it. Each of these `div`'s includes a heading text, then a picture part and right of the picture some text.

The parts themselves are situated in a `<div id="content">` themselves (thus all parts are children of this main `div`, which is centered horizontally on the screen and situated below the mainmenu (relative)).

The picture part is a div which contains 2 canvases which are displayed at the same position so that a transition effect can be made on mouseover.

The number of "parts" is known and also the elements of which the div consists of don't change.

**Detailed picture**

[image]

**Example sourcecode**

```
<div id="content" width="800px">
    <div id="part1">
        <span class="highlight">Headling</span>
        <div id="part1image" class="floatleft">
            <canvas height="100" width="100" id="part1image1"></canvas>
            <canvas height="100" width="100" id="part1image2"></canvas>
        </div>
        <span class="text2">Text</span>
    </div>
    <div id="part2">
        <span class="highlight">Headling</span>
        <div id="part2image" class="floatleft">
            <canvas height="100" width="100" id="part2image1"></canvas>
            <canvas height="100" width="100" id="part2image2"></canvas>
        </div>
        <span class="text2">Text<br/> Text line 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the text multi-line?

Comment: yes. The text itself is multiline (as I have control over the text I can put in <br/> where needed so no automatic word wrapping needed.

also the typical width of content is 800 px  (edited the code to show this)

Comment: What CSS have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tg4xn/)) is the closest I can come. I had to add an extra wrapping `<div>`, to make sure the headings did not become inline.

A summary of the code:

- The elements are `inline-block`, to make sure they are in line
- The `.floatleft` class has relative positioning, so that the canvases can stack. It also has a fixed `width` and `height` because there are no elements in the `div` that are positioned normally.